# How to set the slider max value and how to make two way binding for the slider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following the example provided [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PRg5h/1/) , I have fit the slider as per the requirement

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Rating</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">     
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>           

        <script src="test.js"></script>   
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">       
        <div ng-controller="testController">                    
                <table>                 
                    <tr>
                        <td>Amount:</td>                                        
                        <td><div slider ng-model="amount" style="width:200px;"></div></td>
                        <td><input type= "text" ng-model="amount" id="txtAmount"></td>
                    </tr>                                                       
                </table>                                            
             </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

### test.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("testController", function($scope, $http){

    $scope.amount = 1;

}); //end controller

myApp.directive('slider', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
              ngModel: '='
          },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

          console.log(scope.ngModel);

          return $(elem).slider({
            range: "min",
            animate: true,
            value: scope.ngModel,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
              return scope.$apply(function(){
                scope.ngModel = ui.value;
              });
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

The problem is that

a) Max range cannot be set beyond 100. Say I want the min value as 1 and max as 1000. How to do that?

[image]

b) Two way binding is not happening. Say if I set the value of the "txtAmount " to 50, then the slider should point to that value(50)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Max range could be changed using [`max` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max) you can see it in an example down below. If `max` field won't be specified in element it will set a maximum to 100.
2. Two binding is working for Angular's elements because it's watching for changes, so you basically need to do the same for jQuery element

Code:

```
scope.$watch('ngModel', function(val) {
  $(elem).slider("value", val);
});
```

Full fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zv78jsz6/